# Suggest a good CRM system for F2P game

Tags: crm

Could anyone please suggest which one is a good CRM solution for an online F2P game.
We found few options like Exact Target, Sailthrou or Pardot but not able to decide on the pros and cons.

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to prototype some free options and see what works best for different use cases you would need. The goal here would be to put the least amount of effort into your trials and see how much value you can gain from the systems functionality.

Planning and Prototyping your business processes and ideas now before implementation will save you lots of cost (both time and money) in the future.

Good luck.

Microsoft Dynamics 30 day free trial
http://www.microsoft.com/dynamics/en/asia/crm-free-trial-overview.aspx

salesforce 30 day free trial
https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/freetrial-sales.jsp

Exact Target is more of a marketing solution than a full CRM solution. It works good with many CRM systems out there.